# How to implement transformation of a struct to a similar struct in Go

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have 2 structs and one of them is made of protobuf, the other is made from xorm`s table struct.

There is a function which needs []*UserResult but I only have []*Users.

How do I transform them?

```
//user.proto => 
message UserResult {
  int64 uid = 1 ;
  string name = 2 ;
}
//user.go
type User struct {
   uid int64 
   name string 
}
func GetUserList(){
   var users []*User
   return xorm.xxxx.Get(&users)
}

// server.go 
func (s *server)GetUserList() ([]*UserRequest , error) {
    users := model.GetUsers()
    // here  how to make users --->  []*UserRequest ???
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a for loop:

```
var userRequests []* UserRequest
users := model.GetUsers()
for _, u := range users {
  ur := &UserRequest{name:u.Name, uid:u.uid, etc...}
  userRequests = append(userRequests,ur)
}
```

You could use a function NewUserRequest(u) instead of constructing a ur inline like this. You haven't shown UserRequest so the fields would have to be adapted to whatever fields you have in there.

Comment: As long as the two structs have the same type layout and field names, you don't have to do a field-by-field assembly, you can simply directly type-convert them: https://play.golang.org/p/FqR0-W-BF7

Comment: this won't work since this: https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/607

Answer (score 0):

The generated from (`user.proto`) should have JSON annotations on them. By adding JSON annotations to your type in `user.go` you can marshal the `User` and unmarshal it into a `UserRequest` and vice-versa. Note that this approach is not very performant (it uses a lot of unnecessary cpu for marshaling JSON and creates a bit of garbage to collect), it is however easy to do for a type that has many fields or one that changes a lot.

Another approach would be to use [reflection](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/). This will allow you to convert between any two types with the same fields.
Might be a little faster than JSON, but not as fast as function that converts between the two.

Comment: Don't even need json annotations, as long as the field names are the same (JSON defaults to using the case-sensitive field name, and then if there's no match, the case-insensitive field name).  The problem is, the fields have to be exported, which they currently are not.